# Split a given std::variant type by a given criteria

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant

How to by a given variant type

```
using V = std::variant<bool, char, std::string, int, float, double, std::vector<int>>;
```

declare two variant types

```
using V1 = std::variant<bool, char, int, float, double>;
using V2 = std::variant<std::string, std::vector<int>>;
```

where `V1` includes all the arithmetic types from `V` and `V2` includes all non-arithmetic types from `V`?

`V` can be a parameter of a template class, for example:

```
template <class V>
struct TheAnswer
{
    using V1 = ?;
    using V2 = ?;
};
```

in general the criteria can be a `constexpr` variable like this:

```
template <class T>
constexpr bool filter;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If for whatever reason you don't want to use Barry's short and reasonable answer, here is one that is neither (thanks @[xskxzr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5376789/xskxzr) for removing the awkward "bootstrap" specialization, and to @[max66](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6022656/max66) for warning me against the empty variant corner case):

```
namespace detail {
    template <class V>
    struct convert_empty_variant {
        using type = V;
    };

    template <>
    struct convert_empty_variant<std::variant<>> {
        using type = std::variant<std::monostate>;
    };

    template <class V>
    using convert_empty_variant_t = typename convert_empty_variant<V>::type;

    template <class V1, class V2, template <class> class Predicate, class V>
    struct split_variant;

    template <class V1, class V2, template <class> class Predicate>
    struct split_variant<V1, V2, Predicate, std::variant<>> {
        using matching = convert_empty_variant_t<V1>;
        using non_matching = convert_empty_variant_t<V2>;
    };

    template <class... V1s, class... V2s, template <class> class Predicate, class Head, class... Tail>
    struct split_variant<std::variant<V1s...>, std::variant<V2s...>, Predicate, std::variant<Head, Tail...>>
    : std::conditional_t<
        Predicate<Head>::value,
        split_variant<std::variant<V1s..., Head>, std::variant<V2s...>, Predicate, std::variant<Tail...>>,
        split_variant<std::variant<V1s...>, std::variant<V2s..., Head>, Predicate, std::variant<Tail...>>
    > { };
}

template <class V, template <class> class Predicate>
using split_variant = detail::split_variant<std::variant<>, std::variant<>, Predicate, V>;
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lZmfyicPb13n2CzH)

Comment: Maybe you can unpack `Types...` inside `std::variant` directly,  like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2D9MRKQqv0BZlLoc)?

Comment: Sorry, but... as far I know, a empty `std::variant` is ill-formed.

Comment: @max66 Apparently only [instantiating](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.variant#3.sentence-1) `std::variant<>` is ill-formed, so I'm in the clear. I will tweak it so that `V1` and `V2` fall back to `std::variant<std::monostate>` though.

Comment: Ah... ill-formed only if instantiated... OK; seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 14):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_filterp_l), this is a short one-liner (as always):

```
using V1 = mp_filter<std::is_arithmetic, V>;
using V2 = mp_remove_if<V, std::is_arithmetic>;
```

You can also use:

```
using V1 = mp_copy_if<V, std::is_arithmetic>;
```

to make the two more symmetric.

---

Alternatively,

```
using P = mp_partition<V, std::is_arithmetic>;
using V1 = mp_first<P>;
using V2 = mp_second<P>;
```

Comment: What ideas is this `mp_filter` based on?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky I don't understand the question - what do you mean, what ideas?

Comment: I do not understand why you do not understand :) I mean what technique does it use to transform `std::variant`?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Read the documentation, it also links to some posts that Peter wrote, it's quite informative.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin It's the best metaprogramming library imo. I have a lot of answers on here that start with "With Boost.Mp11, this is a short one-liner"

Comment: @Barry I am reading the docs right now and it looks much better than boost.MPL.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** Given that a empty variant (`std::variant<>`) is ill formed (according [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)) and that should be used `std::variant<std::monostate>` instead, I've modified the answer (added a `tuple2variant()` specialization for empty tuple) to support the case when the list of types for `V1` or `V2` is empty.

---

It's a little `decltype()` delirium but... if you declare a helper filter couple of function as follows

```
template <bool B, typename T>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<B == std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, std::tuple<T>>
   filterArithm ();

template <bool B, typename T>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<B != std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, std::tuple<>>
   filterArithm ();
```

and a tuple to variant function (with a specialization for empty tuples, to avoid a empty `std::variant`)

```
std::variant<std::monostate> tuple2variant (std::tuple<> const &);

template <typename ... Ts>
std::variant<Ts...> tuple2variant (std::tuple<Ts...> const &);
```

your class simply (?) become

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct TheAnswer<std::variant<Ts...>>
 {
   using V1 = decltype(tuple2variant(std::declval<
                 decltype(std::tuple_cat( filterArithm<true, Ts>()... ))>()));
   using V2 = decltype(tuple2variant(std::declval<
                 decltype(std::tuple_cat( filterArithm<false, Ts>()... ))>()));
 };
```

If you want something more generic (if you want to pass `std::arithmetic` as a template parameter), you can modify the `filterArithm()` function passing a template-template filter parameter `F` (renamed `filterType()`)

```
template <template <typename> class F, bool B, typename T>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<B == F<T>::value, std::tuple<T>>
   filterType ();

template <template <typename> class F, bool B, typename T>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<B != F<T>::value, std::tuple<>>
   filterType ();
```

The `TheAnswer` class become

```
template <typename, template <typename> class>
struct TheAnswer;

template <typename ... Ts, template <typename> class F>
struct TheAnswer<std::variant<Ts...>, F>
 {
   using V1 = decltype(tuple2variant(std::declval<decltype(
                 std::tuple_cat( filterType<F, true, Ts>()... ))>()));
   using V2 = decltype(tuple2variant(std::declval<decltype(
                 std::tuple_cat( filterType<F, false, Ts>()... ))>()));
 };
```

and the `TA` declaration take also `std::is_arithmetic`

```
using TA = TheAnswer<std::variant<bool, char, std::string, int, float,
                                  double, std::vector<int>>,
                     std::is_arithmetic>;
```

The following is a full compiling example with `std::is_arithmetic` as parameter and a `V2` empty case

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>

std::variant<std::monostate> tuple2variant (std::tuple<> const &);

template <typename ... Ts>
std::variant<Ts...> tuple2variant (std::tuple<Ts...> const &);

template <template <typename> class F, bool B, typename T>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<B == F<T>::value, std::tuple<T>>
   filterType ();

template <template <typename> class F, bool B, typename T>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<B != F<T>::value, std::tuple<>>
   filterType ();

template <typename, template <typename> class>
struct TheAnswer;

template <typename ... Ts, template <typename> class F>
struct TheAnswer<std::variant<Ts...>, F>
 {
   using V1 = decltype(tuple2variant(std::declval<decltype(
                 std::tuple_cat( filterType<F, true, Ts>()... ))>()));
   using V2 = decltype(tuple2variant(std::declval<decltype(
                 std::tuple_cat( filterType<F, false, Ts>()... ))>()));
 };

int main ()
 {
   using TA = TheAnswer<std::variant<bool, char, std::string, int, float,
                                     double, std::vector<int>>,
                        std::is_arithmetic>;
   using TB = TheAnswer<std::variant<bool, char, int, float, double>,
                        std::is_arithmetic>;

   using VA1 = std::variant<bool, char, int, float, double>;
   using VA2 = std::variant<std::string, std::vector<int>>;
   using VB1 = VA1;
   using VB2 = std::variant<std::monostate>;

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<VA1, TA::V1> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<VA2, TA::V2> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<VB1, TB::V1> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<VB2, TB::V2> );
 }
```

Comment: @xskxzr - Sorry but I don't understand your objection. `void`, as far I know, is forbidden as type in a `std::variant`.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize `std::variant<void>` is ill-formed, but it seems [`std::variant<>` is OK if its definition is not instantiated](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/variant#variant-3).